# Using SubSonic2.2

Tags: subsonic

I just download the SubSonic2.2 and use it but many of my prev codes ( Insert in tables when I have an Identity or unique field) throw errors ,also scraffold component can't insert in this tables.
I saw the SubSonic version in SubCommander is 2.1 and maybe this make problem, I can't find any other version that has SubSonic2.2.

While Subsonic use Google Codes and this site block access to its site from a fewccountires such as Iran , I can't access to code and compile it.
Where can I find a SubCommander version who works with subSonic 2.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try an anonymous proxy on the internet to "fake" what country you are in.